# Using a Float Action Button Crossing Over Content and make it Scrollable

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code and I want to make it Scrollable, all it's content, what's the best way to make it? I tried just making ScrollView parent of all code but it just doesn't work, it only makes all white and not scrollable.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewOne"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        app:rippleColor="#FFF" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance guys

Comment: Did you look into the Scrollview layout